# Tools for running distributed API Tests

Tags: api, testing, grid, virtual-machine, distributed

I want to run API tests on a VM or physical machine.

(as we do with selenium grid : keep tests on hub and run it on node)

Is there a tool that can handle this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jmeter for distributed testing
or load testing
https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html

Comment: thanks , i will try

Comment: please accept the answer if it answer your question